# Workflow to 'Update' existing Calendar event

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a workflow that creates a calendar event when I set an item's 'Completed' field to 'Yes'.  I want the workflow to update this same calendar event every time the list item is edited.  At the moment my workflow creates a new calendar event which is not my desired outcome.  How do I update the old calendar event rather than create a new one?

Best Regards
Dave

Answer (score 0):

You create a new item call will return an itemid for the created calendar item. You want to save this itemid in for example a column.

So every time the workflow runs you first check if the itemid is already there.

If the itemid is there use the update list item action to update the item where the id matches your saved itemid.

If the itemid is not there you know you still need to create the calendar item.